# Java polynomial division infinite loop

Tags: java, loops

I have to create a calculator for polynomials. All operations work perfectly except the division. I have tried to debug it and see why it is looping and I found out that after ending a for instruction, it jumps back to the begining.

I wrote my classes in here.
http://pastebin.com/1vCkS2WW

In the Operatii Class, when the second for ends, it jumps back to where. Can you please tell me why this happens and what should i do to end it ?

Comment: There's a lot to read there.  Perhaps you could post the smallest complete program that you need, to reproduce the problem.  Also, have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?  What did you learn?

Comment: Looks like a good time to use the code formatter in your IDE and then use the debugger to step through the code to see where the code does something you don't expect.

Comment: As the guys above have mentioned it's a bit hard to tell what is happening in the code as it is quite long, but one thing that pops out is the "i" variable on line 132. I can see you are incrementing it on line 160. This is outside the while loop and could be the reason/part of the reason you get infinite looping... Try going through the code as @PeterLawrey suggested using the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

At line 132 you have a while loop with one of the conditions is i < 5 but you don't increment the variable inside the loop so it will never exit.

Answer (score 0):

After second for loop you are coming back to while, because that you have wrote your code. To end it you should make sure that condition in while is changed to `false`. Your `i` variable is always lower than 5, so take care of the first part of condition.